# Writing a middleware for all subscriptions on all observables

Tags: angular

I subscribe to many API methods in my angular.io project. Is it technically possible to write a middleware so that I will check all responses for a specific response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Angular's [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http), you can use an [interceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses):

> HTTP Interception is a major feature of @angular/common/http. With interception, you declare interceptors that inspect and transform HTTP requests from your application to the server. The same interceptors may also inspect and transform the server's responses on their way back to the application. Multiple interceptors form a forward-and-backward chain of request/response handlers.

The documentation has some examples, like caching, logging, and others.